# How to make static function calls for all subclasses in an array loop?

Tags: swift

All of the subclasses has a static function `update` and I have to call them for each subclass:

```
class subClass1 {
    static func update() { ... }
}

subClass1.update()
subClass2.update()
subClass3.update()
```

I hope I can construct an array to store them and call them like this:

```
let allSubClasses: [baseClass.Type] = [
    subClass1.self,
    subClass2.self,
    subClass3.self,
]

for var i=0; i<allSubClasses.count; ++i {
    allSubClasses[i].update()  // something like this, how to achieve it?
}
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Your first problem is the wrong syntax in the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you do it. Declare it as a class method,

```
class BaseClass {
    class func update() {

    }
}


class Subclass1: BaseClass {
    override class func update() {
        print("Subclass1")
    }
}

class Subclass2: BaseClass {
    override class func update() {
        print("Subclass2")
    }
}

class  Subclass3: BaseClass {
    override class func update() {
        print("Subclass3")
    }
}



let allSubclasses: [BaseClass.Type] = [
    Subclass1.self,
    Subclass2.self,
    Subclass3.self
]

for i in 0 ..< allSubclasses.count {
   allSubclasses[i].update()
}
```

I would guess that you had it as static which would make your method a final and so you cannot override that in your base classes.

Answer (score 2):

Given a base class

```
class Animal {
    class func update() { }
}
```

and 2 subclasses

```
class Dog: Animal { }
class Cat: Animal { }
```

This is how you create an array of class types

```
let animals: [Animal.Type] = [Dog.self, Cat.self]
```

And this is how you invoke the `update` <strike>static</strike> class function

```
for animal in animals {
    animal.update()
}
```